# Crystal Reports: How to make a report with Monthly, Quarterly, and YTD field totals?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

Here is an abbreviated example of the table I am working with:

```
Month ............ SiteID ........ Patients ....FundingSource.... Year
January ............ 1 ........... 13 .......... ABCD.......... 2019
February............ 1 ........... 223 ......... ABCD.......... 2019
February ........... 2 ........... 52 .......... ABCD.......... 2019
February ........... 3 ........... 21........... EFGH.......... 2018
March .............. 1 ........... 44 .......... EFGH.......... 2018
April .............. 1 ........... 12 .......... ABCD.......... 2019
May................. 1 ........... 34 .......... ABCD.......... 2018
May................. 1 ........... 51 .......... ABCD.......... 2019
June ............... 1 ............62 .......... EFGH.......... 2017
```

I am trying to output a report that shows the monthly, quarterly, and Year to Date totals of number of patients seen for the given parameters. The Parameters are FundingSource, SiteID, Month , Year. Because the report is supposed to look like a form it has to print the result out one time/on one page.

Edit: The quarterly total should be for the fiscal quarter, which is from July to June. The Year column is the calendar year.

The Patients field itself is a string field representing the number of patients seen in the month. So creating a monthly total is easy because it is just a matter of adding the field.

For the Quarterly total I made a Cdbl Formula field to convert the table.Patients to a number (it is an nvarchar field in our database -- can't to a sum in the running total field), then made a running total field for each quarter for that field (by making that cdbl field evaluate for Month IN [January, February, March, April], etc, and reset on change of SiteID). Then I made another formula field which would output the corresponding running total field for the quarter for whichever month

ex.

```
 IF month IN [January, February, March, April] then
{#PatientsSeenQ1}
```

The problem I'm having is that given these parameter fields, The Quarterly result ends up being the same as the Monthly result, because Month = ?Month and it can't zoom out to capture the other months in the quarter. I think this is the same problem with getting the YTD total as well.

I've been banging my head against this problem for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated!! This is an important problem for my job so I will definitely respond promptly.

EDIT:

I'm asked to format the output like this (assuming calendar year quarters for example purposes):

```
Reporting Period: May 2019
Funding Source: ABCD
Site: 1

........................... Monthly ... Quarterly ..... YTD
Number of patients seen:..... 51 ........ 63........... 299
```

I don't have to report for each site, year, and month, only for the entered site, year, funding source and month (the parameters). The output is supposed to be a printable version of a report that users will view on a website.

EDIT:

With the below from user heringer I was able to find the solutions to my problems. For the YTD I had outside help, so here is that answer:

I made one formula field @FiscalYear to determine the year:

```
IF {@RowMonthCDate} IN [7,8,9,10,11,12] and {@ParMonthCDate} IN [1,2,3,4,5,6] THEN toText((ToNumber({?Year})-1),"#")
ELSE IF {@RowMonthCDate} IN [1,2,3,4,5,6] and {@ParMonthCDate} IN [7,8,9,10,11,12] THEN toText((ToNumber({?Year})+1),"#")
ELSE toText((ToNumber({?Year})),"#")
```

Then for the YTD Running total field I put this for the Evaluate formula:

```
 {reporting_year} = {@FiscalYear} AND
(
     if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 7  then  {@RowMonthCDate} = 7
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 8  then  {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 9  then  {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 10 then  {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 11 then  {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 12 then  {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12]

else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 1 then {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12,1]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 2 then {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 3 then {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 4 then {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 5 then {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5]
else if  {@ParMonthCDate} = 6 then {@RowMonthCDate} in [7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]
) 
AND
 {report.fundingsource} = {?FundingSource} AND
 {report.Site_id} = {?Site_ID}
```

Maybe not elegant, but it gives me the total for the field up to the Parameter Month for that fiscal year. Thank you again to heringer for working with me for about a week on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a formula to build a Date using the year and the month (and consider day 1).

Then create 3 groups by this formula.

Use group expert to each group to make then yearly, quaterly, monthly.

Then put simple summary fields on the groups footers.

I am not sure if it fits in your final design. If not, please show it.

**EDIT:**

After the new comments, here is a new purposed solution. I will keep the old one above for futher reference.

Based com comments, i am assuming that the report will show data for one year, one month, one funding source and one siteid.

I understand you started at the right directions. I will try to help with the details.

1. Create the parameters: {?Year}, {?Month}, {?FundingSource?}, {?SideId}.
2. Create running total field {#PatientsInMonth} to sum {Table.Patients} and set "evaluate / use a formula" with this formula:

```
{Table.Year} = {?Year} AND
{Table.Month} = {?Month} AND
{Table.FundingSource} = {?FundingSource} AND
{Table.SiteId} = {?SiteId}
```

3. Create running total field {#PatientsInQuarter} to sum {Table.Patients} and set "evaluate / use a formula" with this formula:

```
 numbervar rowNumberOfMonth := 0; //TODO i'm letting it up to you, since you said you did it
 numbervar parNumberOfMonth := 0; //TODO
 numbervar rowQuarter := (rowNumberOfMonth - 1) \ 4; //notice the integer divide, the symbol is not wrong
 numbervar parQuarter := (parNumberOfMonth - 1) \ 4; //notice the integer divide, the symbol is not wrong
 {Table.Year} = {?Year} AND
 rowQuarter = parQuarter AND
 {Table.FundingSource} = {?FundingSource} AND
 {Table.SiteId} = {?SiteId}
```

4. Create running total field {#PatientsInYear} to sum {Table.Patients} and set "evaluate / use a formula" with this formula:

```
 {Table.Year} = {?Year} AND
 {Table.FundingSource} = {?FundingSource} AND
 {Table.SiteId} = {?SiteId}
```

5. Put the running total fields in report footer.

Comment: Hi again! Thank you. I have added the final design I have been asked to apply to the report: I'm not sure this solution will work for it, since the monthly, quarterly, and YTD are all supposed to be on the same line? If not, and there is no other solution, then I can go from there, but I wonder what you think with this new info.

Comment: Do you group the report by year-month, source and site? And show all the occurrences?

Comment: Hi! I hope I understand you correctly: I don't have to report for each site, year, and month, only for the entered site, year, funding source and month (the parameters). The output is supposed to be a printable version of a report that users will view on a website. (I will add this to the original question)

Comment: Oh man, putting the formulas into the running total fields is exactly what I was missing. For the quarterly field, I did figure out how to convert the month to a number; however, I should have clarified in my question (I will do that now) that the quarterly fields are the FISCAL quarters, with our fiscal year running from July to June -- the Year column is the calendar year, however. Also, the Year total is the year to date, so it can't be just the ?Year: Is there any way to make these totals without writing them out long-form as case or if then statements? I will update my question with this.

Comment: I didn't get it. Are you saying that, for example, for May the quarter would be March, April, May, and June? If so, just shift both quarters calculations. Ex: (6 + rowNumberOfMonth - 1) \ 4

Comment: For May the quarter would be April, May and June (Q4). What do rowNumberofMonth and parNumberofMonth mean? Also, how can I find the Year to Date total, instead of just the total for the calendar year. The confusion on my side is that the table.year field will change in the middle of a YTD calculation for some months (January, Feb, March, April, May, June), because it is the calendar year, not the fiscal year. Thank you so much.

Comment: rowNumberOfMonth is the month number that corresponds to the value of the "Month" column in the current row during the processing, while similarly parNumberofMonth is the month number that corresponds to the value of the parameter month entered by the user.

Comment: So the year 2019 = from july 2018 until june 2019, is that what you mean about the year?

Comment: Cool, thank you! Exactly, while the year field is the calendar year, the Year to Date column is requested for the fiscal year up until the parmonth.

Comment: So, replace the use of the parameter {?Year} by a formula {@FiscalYear}. The formula should be something like it: if {Table.Month} <= {?Month} then {Table.Year} else {Table.Year} - 1. Think if it is necessary to treat "future months" (after {?Month}). If so, you will need to work the formula {@FiscalYear} to add +1 in that case.

Comment: Hi again, this works great, except it still gives me the full year. Ex. for parameters April 2014 it gives me all the way back to April 2013, when really I just need until July 2013. Also, the quarterly column is not quite right -- it is giving me four months instead of three: can you explain the logic of the integer math?  I am learning a lot from you, thanks.

Comment: The formula intends to calculate the quarter to which the month belongs. It must be an integer divide, because you need to months 1,2,3,4 hit the same quarter.

Comment: Hi again, changing the integer divide to / 3 is now giving me the correct results (a quarter has three months); with your help (and one of my co-workers) I have been able to figure out the rest! Thank you very much! I have added my YTD solution to my question.

Comment: I see. So quarter is 1/4 :) The translation to my language is ambigous in Google Translator. So is in my mind :)